Android ¿Se puede acceder al contexto en un viewmodel del hilt instanciado by viewModels?
Necesito acceder a las preferences para saber una fecha de caducidad de una cookie, pero necesito resolverlo en el vm.
@HiltViewModel
class SplashScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel() {

    private val _isLoaded = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isLoaded : LiveData<Boolean> = _isLoaded

    suspend fun setDelay() {
        _isLoaded.value = false
        delay(2000)
        _isLoaded.value = true
    }
}


Tal vez tengas que usar un AndroidViewModel

Si se puede, si estás usando un Fragment o Activity y usas "by viewModels()" con HILT puedes modificar de esta forma tu clase para obtener el contexto:
@HiltViewModel
class SplashScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(private val context: Context): ViewModel() {

   //Dentro puedes hacer uso del contexto mediante la variable context, en cualquiera de los métodos de la clase

}

